# How to create async iterator over callback which calls back multiple times (or a stream) in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, async-iterator

How do I get this working in TypeScript? [Here is the EventIterator library](https://github.com/rolftimmermans/event-iterator), which seems to make it possible to build a queue to handle the callbacks of the xhr progress event nicely.

```
import { EventIterator } from 'event-iterator'

export async function* requestAndWaitForWorkToComplete(request: Request) {
  for await (const data of callXhr(request)) {
    yield data

    switch (data.type) {
      case 'request-progress':
        console.log('progress', data.percentComplete)
        break
      // ...
    }
  }
  // TODO: do more stuff here.
}


export type RequestBody = FormData | object

export type Request = {
  path: string
  method: string
  body: RequestBody
}

export type RequestProgress = {
  type: 'request-progress'
  request: Request
  percentComplete: number
}

export type RequestComplete = {
  type: 'request-complete'
  request: Request
}

export type RequestFailure = {
  type: 'request-failure'
  request: Request
}

export type CallXhr = RequestProgress | RequestComplete | RequestFailure

export async function* callXhr(
  request: Request,
): AsyncIterator<CallXhr> {
  return new EventIterator<CallXhr>(({ push }) => {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
    let body
    if (typeof request.body === 'string') {
      body = request.body
      xhr.setRequestHeader('content-type', 'application/json')
    } else if (request.body instanceof FormData) {
      body = request.body
      // headers['content-type'] = 'multipart/form-data'
    } else {
      body = JSON.stringify(body)
      xhr.setRequestHeader('content-type', 'application/json')
    }

    const isAsync = true

    xhr.open(request.method, request.path, isAsync)

    xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', (e: ProgressEvent) => {
      const percentComplete = (e.loaded / e.total) * 100
      push({ type: 'request-progress', percentComplete, request })
    })

    xhr.addEventListener('load', function () {
      if (this.status == 200) {
        push({ type: 'request-complete', request })
      } else {
        push({ type: 'request-failure', request })
      }
    })

    xhr.send(body)
  })
}
```

Right at `callXhr(request)` I am getting this in TypeScript:

```
Type 'AsyncIterator<CallXhr, any, undefined>' must have a '[Symbol.asyncIterator]()' method that returns an async iterator.ts(2504)
(alias) callXhr(request: Request): AsyncIterator<CallXhr, any, undefined>
import callXhr
```

I don't know if I have typed the `callXhr` function properly, or really what else I need to add to get this to work. Without the type annotation on `callXhr` I get this on the `data.type` call in the switch statement:

```
Property 'type' does not exist on type 'never'.ts(2339)
```

I would have assumed the `EventIterator`, which is [`class EventIterator<T> extends AsyncIterator<T>`](https://github.com/rolftimmermans/event-iterator/blob/d7699d3d6e8bf3fa82c7cd42dc1a0a44e342b6d9/src/event-iterator.ts#L140) would have the type figured out automatically.

How do I properly type this in TypeScript? I have this in my `tsconfig.json`, do I need to change anything so it works cross-browser?

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "ESNext",
    "target": "ES2020",
    "lib": ["es2020", "dom"],
    ...
  }
}
```

I tried changing `"target": "esnext"` but it didn't seem to have any effect.

Also, if there is a simpler way to handle the `xhr` progress callback without using the third-party library, feel free to show how to do that :). But not a requirement.

Comment: Just drop the `async` and `*` - you want `export function callXhr(request: Request): AsyncIterator<CallXhr> { return … }`. Don't write an async generator function if you're using neither `yield` nor `await`.

Comment: @Bergi Here's what I landed on: https://github.com/termsurf/task/blob/af2c9959833344651b35a5a6be19a7f336174a89/code/tool/shared/work.ts#L34 Hopefully I don't regret it haha.

Comment: Why does that always `yield data`? Looks weird and long-winded to me to always handle different yielded values with `switch` statements.